# Swift allowVibrancy

Tags: nsview, nsvisualeffectview

How do I set a view to allow vibrancy in swift.
I'm trying:

```
func allowsVibrancy() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

but getting an error:
Method 'allowsVibrancy()' with Objective-C selector 'allowsVibrancy' conflicts with getter for 'allowsVibrancy' from superclass 'NSView' with the same Objective-C selector

or even:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.allowsVibrancy = true
    println(self.allowsVibrancy)
}
```

I can do this in Onjective C with:

```
- (BOOL)allowsVibrancy {
    return YES;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You should override property, not method

```
override var allowsVibrancy: Bool { return true }
```